# How to create slider ticks in silverlight using c#

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, slider, silverlight-5.0

I am a C# Silverlight 5 beginner and I have a situation where I have to create a slider using only C# code(not xaml).

I am successfully able to display a slider but the problem Silverlight don't have any slight tick management.

What I want is a GUI like this:

[image]

And currently I have this GUI :

[image]

So I have to add -2 and 2 at starting and end and I also have to add tick marks.

But I couldn't find the way to do that in Silverlight 5.

My current code looks something like this:

```
Slider slider1 = new Slider();
TextBox txtblk6 = new TextBox(); 

private static Grid GenertateSlider(ViewModel.XmlParameterClasses.Parameter param, int LoopCount)
{
    // Create a new slider and add a ValueChanged event handler.        
    slider1.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    slider1.Width = 100;
    slider1.Maximum = param.Component.Attributes.Max; //It is the Maximum value (-2 in my case)
    slider1.Minimum = param.Component.Attributes.Min;//(-1 in my case)
  // slider1
    Grid.SetColumn(txtblk6, 2);
    Grid.SetRow(txtblk6, LoopCount); //Here LoopCount is to decide the row number and is passed through function call.
    g.Children.Add(txtblk6);

    txtblk6.Text = slider1.Value.ToString() + " Pips";
    slider1.ValueChanged += Slider_ValueChanged1;
    Grid.SetColumn(slider1, 1);
    Grid.SetRow(slider1, LoopCount);
    g.Children.Add(slider1);
    return (g);
}
```

and

```
private void Slider_ValueChanged1(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
       {
           // Add code to perform some action here.
           txtblk6.Text = slider1.Value.ToString() + " Pips";
       }
```

**Could some one please let me know that how to add?**

(1) Slider Ticks ?

(2) -2  0  and 2 as in given GUI ?

(3) How to show just show data as round off (because right now it shows in terms of 0.555797478 ; I mean very monng but i want it as 0.6 instead of this very long value) ?

Would be a big help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll find a sample of slider with tick values [here](http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2009/04/12/slider-with-ticks/).

[It's pretty old but it might do the trick for you.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/gg986858%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Is it without xaml? you know i just have to code in c# only .

Comment: It uses a class called CustomSlider extending Slider that's only a .cs

Comment: Thanks Ok let me apply it .Will come soon to mark your answer if it works.

Comment: The problem is it uses xaml code for GUI which i can't use. I just have to code in c#

Comment: Just use the CustomSlider class you won't need any xaml

Comment: Ok, But i am not able to understand that how to attach it to the grid("g" in my case) ? Could you please help me inb doing it, Its very confusing for me also complex.

Comment: and you can see that i am getting everythinbg dynamically from object "param.Component.Attributes" so nothing is static (this objkect is obtained on deserializing xml)

Comment: have you try just to change your Slider object to CustomSlider ?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'CustomSlider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53965/discussion-between-florent-gz-and-user234839)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with doing it like this?

```
private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid g = new Grid();
        g.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        g.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        g.Height = 68;
        g.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        g.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

        Slider slider = new Slider();
        slider.TickPlacement = TickPlacement.Both;
        slider.Maximum = 2.0;
        slider.Minimum = -2.0;
        slider.TickFrequency = 0.5;
        slider.Height = 40;
        slider.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        Grid.SetRow(slider, 0);
        g.Children.Add(slider);

        TextBlock t1 = new TextBlock();
        t1.Height = 28;
        t1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
        t1.Text = "-2";
        Grid.SetRow(t1, 1);
        g.Children.Add(t1);

        TextBlock t2 = new TextBlock();
        t2.Height = 28;
        t2.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        t2.Text = "0";
        Grid.SetRow(t2, 1);
        g.Children.Add(t2);

        TextBlock t3 = new TextBlock();
        t3.Height = 28;
        t3.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        t3.Text = "2";
        Grid.SetRow(t3, 1);
        g.Children.Add(t3);

        theGrid.Children.Add(g);
    }
```

What have I overlooked?

Comment: Error:'System.Windows.Controls.Slider' does not contain a definition for 'TickPlacement' and no extension method 'TickPlacement' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Slider' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference ? :ITS A SILVERLIGHT( APPLICATION